# 48 hours into ferment. Fermenter temperature is 73°F. Should I cool it?

Tags: fermentation, beer, fermentation-temperature, first-time-brewer, ipa

First time brewing. I have a IPA in a 6.5 gallon bucket fermenter with US-05 pitched into it. I've got the fermenter in the basement and temperature probe taped to the side of the bucket. Ambient room temperature is around 72°F. The temperature of the probe has been slowly climbing and is at 73.5°F (23°C) this morning. Going on 48 hours since pitching. Steady pulse of bubbling every half second or so in the blowoff container.

Should I try and cool the bucket somehow?

Comment: It is always good to follow yeast package instructions,Safale US-05 works best between 15°C and 22°C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set the fermenter into a tub with 2 inches water in the bottom, and drape a wet t-shirt over the fermenter.  This will cool it off just by about 5 degrees F, which might keep it under 70 F.  To avoid potential fusel alcohols and unusual esters and phenols, you don't want it to get much hotter, so this method is ideal.

Comment: Thanks. I've moved it in a tub but the two inches of water (with star san since there's a spigot on the bucket) ended up being about 5 inches up the side of the bucket. Is that the intent?  I presume we just don't want to cool the wort down too quickly and have the yeast drop?

Comment: 5 inches is just fine. The intent is to cool by evaporation, just like sweat cools us down when we get hot.

Comment: Temps are under 70F now. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Living in Australia I have in the past found it necessary to cease brewing in the summer due to high temperatures. This summer just gone I discovered a solution by way of a newly released dry yeast, Kveik by Lallemand.

According to the manufacturer's website, this yeast supports brewing between 25-40degC (77-104degF). I used it while the ambient temperature in my cellar was 26degC, resulting in a brewing temperature of 28-29degC. Resultant ale was of excellent quality. Independent experiments reported on another site indicate the minimum brewing temperature is below 20degC.

No more high temp blues for me! Kveik will be my go to yeast in summer.

Comment: That's a great idea. I thought Kveik was limited to certain styles of beer but after googling it a bit, that doesn't seem to be the case. Are you trying to control the ferementation temp at all or just letting it naturally swing with daytime highs and night time lows?

Comment: No temp control. Daily temp variation rarely more than 1-2degC. Yearly variation is about 15degC, hence my dilemma and the resulting solution.

Comment: Ok I'll have to try it. It would be nice to just "set-it-and-forget-it" in regards to the fermenter.